# Setting z-index in draggable start and stop events

Tags: z-index, draggable

I want to fix this problem with the z-index of a draggable div.  I have been setting the z-index to be around 99999.  But this causes problems for other elements on the page.  Instead of having a fixed z-index, it occurred to me that a better way could be to set the z-index in the draggable start and stop.

I have this code to do that.

```
$('#id').draggable({ 
    start: function(event, ui) { 
           var $item = ui.draggable;
           $item.css("z-index","999999");
            },
    stop: function(event, ui) {  
           var $item = ui.draggable;
           $item.css("z-index","");
           } 
});
```

This should set the z-index when dragging starts, then set it to an empty string when dragging stops. But it doesn't do it.  What could be wrong?

Someone suggested using the z-index for the ui-draggable-dragging class, but that did not fix the problem either.

```
.ui-draggable-dragging {
    z-index:9999;
}
```

Is that class applied to the element automatically, must it be added in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I was trying to fix is that the draggables did not go beyond the container.  This happened because overflow was specified overflow:hidden.  If I remove this, the code works.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set it to an empty string. Set it to `auto` instead.

```
$(function(){           // Just to make sure we're clear, this must be here.
  $('#id').draggable({ 
    start: function(event, ui) { 
      $(this).css("z-index","999999");
    }, 
    stop: function(event, ui) {  
      $(this).css("z-index","auto");
    } 
  });
});
```

This should, assuming everything else is proper, put it back to its natural `z-index`

Comment: This breaks the draggable behavior.  The div isn't draggable anymore when I add this code.

Comment: To be fair, your original code as printed doesn't appear to drag in the first place – It keeps throwing an error regarding `$item.css` being undefined. I'm going to alter the code completely, but it does what I understand to be what you're asking for.

Comment: The code is the way you have it in this jsfiddle.  But it breaks dragging.  I must comment it out for dragging to happen. http://jsfiddle.net/gkvgn/

Comment: Now the dragging works, but the z-index isn't changed. http://jsfiddle.net/gkvgn/2/

Comment: In Safari 5.1, during the drag, the z-index is changed to 999999 then set to "auto", which places it back at its z-index within the document. Using the web inspector, you can watch the alteration. If it's not doing what *you* expect, please clarify exactly what that is.

Comment: Could it be something about IE 9?

Comment: Indeed it could. Javascript in general is a little screwy in IE. Things that work without a hitch in webkit/mozilla don't respond or throw errors in IE. Check: http://www.vancelucas.com/blog/fixing-ie7-z-index-issues-with-jquery/, http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/fixing-ie-z-index/ , and http://webdeveloper2.com/2010/01/how-to-fix-the-ie-z-index-bug-with-jquery/ . These deal mostly with older versions of IE, but given their track record, the problems probably still exist.